# Why is this going out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, error-handling

I am getting a IndexError: list index out of range error. I'm not sure why. Any advice?

The code is trying to see if a list of numbers is an arithmatic progression, in this case every number is added by 2.

```
def is_arith_progession(num_list):

    delta = num_list[1] - num_list[0]
    for num in num_list:
        if not (num_list[num + 1] - num_list[num] == delta):
        return False
    else:
        return True

print(is_arith_progession([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]))
```

Comment: You never impose a limit of `2` anywhere in your code. Is `delta` always defined as the difference in value between the first two elements in your list?

Comment: `for num in num_list:` iterates over the **values** of your list. You then use the **value+1** to index back into it: `num_list[num + 1]` - does not make much sense.... if you give it a list of `[3,2,1]`the first one already is out of bounds (thislist only has indexes from 0 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying access 5th element of `num_list` array in the second iteration of for loop. After the first iteration `num` becomes 4, so program crashes when it tries to evaluate `num_list[num + 1]`.

`num` variable holds the actual element in the list. It is not index to element.

To iterate over indices, you may try `for num in range(len(num_list) - 1)` which should solve the issue. (Note -1 in the paranthesis)

Comment: i am purposely trying to not use range(len(num_list) - 1). trying to be a little more pretty about it :) Thank you for your response

Comment: @nateph Then you may want to add extra variable `previous` to access loop element of previous iteration. You set this variable in ith iteration and use it in (i+1)th.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for num in num_list:
    if not (num_list[num + 1] - num_list[num] == delta):
        return False
```

almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. When you define `for num in num_list:`, this means that `num` is an *item* from the list `num_list`. `num` is NOT an index. So, if your list is `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`, you go out of bounds when `num` is `4` (i.e. the second item in your list), because your input list is only length 5 and you try to access index `num+1`, which is `5` (indexes are 0 based, so `5` is out of bounds)

You probably want something like this:

```
# Start at index 1, or you'll always return false since delta == index1 - index0
for index in range(1, len(num_list)-1):
    if not (num_list[num + 1] - num_list[num] == delta):
        return False
```

or the more pythonic (note there are no indices):

```
# Again start at index1, zip will handle the edge case of ending nicely so we don't go OB
for num, next_num in zip(num_list[1:], num_list[2:]):
    if not (next_num - num == delta):
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the *values*, not the indexes of the array. So, `num_list[num]` can be out of range. Since you refer to the `i+1` element, iterate up to `i < n-1`

```
for i, _ in enumerate(num_list[:-1]):
    if num_list[i+1] - num_list[i]...
```

Comment: I actually like this answer a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

- `num` is an element of `num_list`, not just an index. Getting an index would be `for num in range(len(num_list)):`, you're effectively calling `num_list[num_list[i]]`;
- Even if it was an index, for the last index `num` in array you are calling numlist[num+1], which is out of array bounds as `num` is already last;

Do `for INDEX in range(len(num_list)-1):` and `if not (num_list[INDEX + 1] - num_list[INDEX] == delta):`. That should do it.